# Why the destructor of a struct in vector are called every time I iterate over them?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I'm trying to implement a HashMap in [LeetCode 706. Design HashMap](https://leetcode.com/problems/design-hashmap/solution/) with C++, it's a simple HashMap with `add`, `remove`, `get` operations:

```cpp
struct Slot {
    int key;
    int val;
    void setValue(int v) {
        cout << "-set " << v << "fo SV"<<endl;
        val = v;
    }
    ~Slot() {
        cout << "dtor Slot " << key << endl;
    }
};

#define BUCKET_SIZE 769
class MyHashMap {
private:
    vector<vector<Slot>> buckets;
    //const int BUCKET_SIZE;
public:
    MyHashMap() :buckets(BUCKET_SIZE, vector<Slot>()) {
    }
    
    void put(int key, int value) {
        auto bucket = buckets[key % BUCKET_SIZE];
        cout << "Add: use bucket " << (key % BUCKET_SIZE) << endl;
        
        for (auto iter = bucket.begin(); iter != bucket.end(); iter++) {
            if (iter->key == key) {
                cout << "Add: update key " << key << " with value " << value << endl;
                *iter = Slot{key, value};
                return;
            }
        }
        
        cout << "Add: push key " << key << " to back with value " << value << endl;
        buckets[key % 769].push_back(Slot{key, value});
    }
    
    int get(int key) {
        auto bucket = buckets[key % BUCKET_SIZE];
        for (auto iter = bucket.begin(); iter != bucket.end(); iter++) {
            if (iter->key == key) {
                return iter->val;
            }
        }
        
        return -1;
    }
    
    void remove(int key) {
        auto bucket = buckets[key % BUCKET_SIZE];
        for (auto iter = bucket.begin(); iter != bucket.end(); iter++) {
            if (iter->key == key) {
                cout << "Remove: remove " << key << endl;
                bucket.erase(iter);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

```
["MyHashMap","put","put","get","get","put","get","remove","get"]
[[],[1,10],[2,2],[1],[3],[2,1],[2],[2],[2]]
```

When I tried to use the HashMap as below:

```cpp
MyHashMap* obj = new MyHashMap();
obj->put(1, 10);
obj->put(2, 2);
obj->get(1);
obj->get(3);
obj->put(2, 1);
obj->get(2);
obj->remove(key);
obj->get(2);
```

The output shows that the destructor of every element in the vector are called:

```
Add: use bucket 1
Add: push key 1 to back with value 10
dtor Slot 1
Add: use bucket 2
Add: push key 2 to back with value 2
dtor Slot 2
dtor Slot 1
Add: use bucket 2
Add: update key 2 with value 1
dtor Slot 2
dtor Slot 2
dtor Slot 2
Remove: remove 2
dtor Slot 2
dtor Slot 2
dtor Slot 1
dtor Slot 2
```

Is there anything I have missed?

Comment: You're copying buckets by value. So when the function ends the buckets are destructed. Take a reference instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `put()`, `get()` and `remove()` methods all making the same mistake.

On this statement:

```
auto bucket = buckets[key % BUCKET_SIZE];
```

`bucket` is a *copy* of the `vector` located at index `key % BUCKET_SIZE`, and thus it makes its own *copy* of all of the `Slot` objects.

You are then looping through, and accessing/modifying, that *copied* `vector`, not the *original* `vector`.

When the method exits, all of those *copies* get destroyed.  That is what you are seeing in your output.

To avoid the copies, you need to change the above statement to this instead:

```
auto &bucket = buckets[key % BUCKET_SIZE];
```

`bucket` will now be a *reference* to the original `vector`, not a *copy*.